# How do i create themes for windows OS?

Tags: windows, themes

I want to know what is the process to create themes for windows OS. I am totally new to this but I know writing codes in Java, Visual Basic and C.
So what are the languages i need know and some good resource to get started.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I would like to create theme for win 8 and 10 primarily but i would like to know ways to do that on 7 and xp

Comment: What OS? XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10?

Comment: primarily for win 8 and 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This detailed article explains on all the possible attributes for a .theme file. You can start coding .theme files with notepad.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note that you can use the .themepack extenstion, but this is more of a program that changes the theme then a theme itself.